# Android application Dissapeared after running for some hours

Tags: android, mobile, crash, gps

I am developing a mobile application, which is used to do travel billing based on GPS Distance Traveled,

I am facing one situation where application is getting vanished after running for more that 10 hours, Any help

Waiting for the reply

Regards
Shashank

Comment: is there any other info e.g. any log trace etc. Also what is the battery status after 10 hours as if the battery is low this can cause shutdown of your app.

Comment: No logs nothing, Battery is in charging mode always , which is attached to a car, if it is charging then GPS will be available for reading other wise ill be turned off, no crash log , just phone is getting restarted after 10 hrs

Comment: are you filtering the log trace for your application only? take a look at the complete log trace to see what else is happening on the phone before it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a service? or a activity? How did you implement it?
If it's only a activity Android could remove your app when you're out of focus any time.

Comment: This is an activity which is Visible from past 5-6 hours and suddenly it was vanished without doing any thing ... no service nothing .. just an Activity running continuously and Total distance calculation running in one thread which is reading GPS data.  it runs fine for about 5-6 Hours and after that it just disappeared, no crash no force close message, even home press is not showing it in history.

Comment: Any thing that you can suggest ?

Comment: Take a WakeLock http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: I am thinking if it is a complete resource consumption issue, may be phone is getting restarted (as android OS does) coz of full utilization of resources,